# Reading Eloquent Javascript, how do they get text from a file?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through eloquent javascript and a few examples have you perform actions on paragraphs of text, which they'll just put in a function for you without explaining how. eg:

"The whole manuscript, as a string value, is available on this page by calling recluseFile function." - http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html

I'm doing the examples in a javascript ide. How can I take the text and store it in a function like in the book, either from a txt file or writing it into the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to check: just open the console on that page, and look for `recluseFile` within JS sources. It'll give you this:

```
function recluseFile() {
  return "% The Book of Programming\n\n%%..."; 
  // a really really long string cut for obvious reasons
}
```

In short, the author of this book just entered the whole text into a one big string literal. That was most probably done with some generator function, of course, but the function itself is pretty darn simple. )

The bottom line: start using browsers' webmaster tools (console), they're capable of giving you answers even to the most cryptic questions. )

Comment: Ohh I see. I thought they were iterating over the story as they had it in the article and not already stripping the new lines and replacing them with \n\n.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in a text file, but save it with .js extension. You should be able to emulate the same in browser or an IDE

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in http://eloquentjavascript.net/js/chapter/fp.js , one of the files included into the sandbox in that chapter.